# Speedster by homepage : Fatal error: Call to a member function setTitle() - after installing that extension. This error is on homeoage

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento. I added a extension Speedster by Fooman on my website after that I am getting error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setTitle() on boolean in /home/trenkey/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register.php on line 43
```

If you wish you can see a live example on https://trenkey.com
I am using Magento 1.9.2.4
your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the extension (or anything else) removed the block named `head` from your layout. Or the code is called in a headless environment (i. e. AJAX request). The reason for this is hard to tell since there's a plethora of potential ones. First thing to do if not done already: refresh all of your caches. Either by issuing `rm -rf var/cache/*` or by using the admin panel: `System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache` (upper right).

If the block is removed from layout, you can try to investigate which code is removing it. Temporarily add the *if* blocks to the methods as shown here:

**app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php**

```
public function unsetBlock($name)
{
    if ( $name === 'head' )
    {
        $e = new Exception();
        var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
    $this->_blocks[$name] = null;
    unset($this->_blocks[$name]);
    return $this;
}

public function removeOutputBlock($blockName)
{
    if ( $blockName === 'head' )
    {
        $e = new Exception();
        var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
    unset($this->_output[$blockName]);
    return $this;
}
```

If this doesn't yield any results, your `head` block is probably never added to layout. In this case you have to go check your layout xml. Start with `app/design/frontend/{YOUR_PACKAGE}/{YOUR_THEME}/layout/page.xml` – if this file doesn't exist, make your way up the theme inheritance path up until `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`: there should be a line inside the `<default>` node looking like this:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
```

If this line exists, it's likely that you're trying to instantiate the customer registration form within an AJAX call. In this case you should either override the block class and remove the `head` dependency or add a `head` block to your AJAX layout (that should render empty).

**NB: Recompile after each step or disable Magento compilation during debugging – or at all since it's usually not recommended nowadays.**

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have tried that all. and I am not able to login into Magento Panel it shows same error.

Comment: Did you also recompile your shop as suggested by @simonthesorcerer?

Comment: Hey Guys, I tried your given method but it still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

The class path shows that you have compilation enabled. In addition to flushing the caches, you must recompile the shop unter System > Compilation.